# Split an image into small image each with XX size

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I want to split an image into few images each in pre define size, mean for example image 30K, into 3 images 10K each.

How to find the size, is it width x height x pixcelBitSize?

if so, all i need then is to find the width height (width x height x pixcelBitSize = 10K) of each image and crop. correct?

Comment: You could find the size of an uncompressed image that way. However, this approach will not work for compressed formats (e.g.: JPEG)

Comment: Depends. I'd say so for bitmaps, but a lot of other image formats have compression algorithms which would screw up the maths somewhat

Answer (score 0):

also, there's a certain amount of non-image header info whose size probably varies with the type of image format used.  You're going to have to look at the official specs to determine that size.  Hopefully, the header will give you the data (type, image size, bit depth, etc.) that would lead you to the correct calculations you need to use.

Comment: Thanks for replay, 

What I did is:
1.I snapshot the screen -> Bitmap
2.Change the image into Jpeg to reduce the image size (must do that for another porpuse)
3.Send this jpeg image to transmitter to send to client : here is my problem, transmitter deal with clients who define different buffers, so ,  I want to do is, before I send the image, I want to split it into few images each have less equal size of the buffer
4.Mean the images is mine, and all should be the same format....

Is this give you more info?, can help how I can manage this?